# Finding the centroid of the two largest contours and display the minimum enclosing circle in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

My code does the following :

1. Grab the video frame.
2. Convert the video frame to the HSV colour space.
3. Split the frame into individual components (separate images for H, S, and V).
4. Apply a threshold to each component
5. Locates the centroid and applies the bounding circle

I can find the two largest contours. From the two largest indexed contours how do I calculate the moments for these contours to find the centroid?

Here is an [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R7g2.png) to help. Blue are the centroids, Red is the minimum enclosing circle and white are the laser pointers (After the threshold has been applied).

```
#Dependacies import
from cmath import inf
from pickle import FRAME
import cv2
from matplotlib.pyplot import hsv
import numpy as np
import imutils

# Video Capture 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")

# Read until video is completed
while(cap.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read() #reading video 

  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #Making hsv frame
  red_lower = np.array ([16, 132, 0])
  red_upper = np.array ([20, 236, 255])
  mask = cv2.inRange (hsv,red_lower,red_upper)
  res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
  thresh = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  if ret== True:
    contours, hiearachy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = sorted(contours,key=cv2.contourArea)
    print ('Number of contours found = ', len(contours))

  if len(contours) >= 2:
    def get_contour_areas(contours):
      all_areas = []
      for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        all_areas.append(area) 
      return all_areas
  
    sorted_contours= sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse= True)
    largest_item= sorted_contours[0]
    second_item= sorted_contours[1]
    cv2.drawContours(frame, largest_item, -1, (255,0,0),1)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, second_item, -1, (255,0,0),1)
 
  if ret == True:
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('gray', thresh)

 # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  # Break the loop
  else: 
    break

# When everything done, release the video capture object
cap.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you add a minimum working example? I do not understand how you calculate size. From my point of understanding, you should 1) get the contours 2) calculate the size for each contour/enclosing circle 3) find the indices of the largest sizes 4) use the indices to select the corresponding contours

Comment: the _two largest_ contours are simply the first/last two contours in a list of contours that you sorted by `contourArea` (`reverse=True` to get largest first). think about it, try to implement it, then report back.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have found the two largest contours using the method you suggested and implemented them in the code. My next challenge is to add the centroids to each of the contours, how would you suggest going about this?

Comment: use `cv.Moments`. it works the same on masks or contours. using m00, m10, m01, you can calculate the centroid.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your help on this project. I have completed the code and updated the thread. This will be used to autofocus a titanium laser etch machine, I need to add motor control etc but that is the easy bit.